# ajax nonce verification failing

Tags: ajax, security, nonce

I have a voting system where a list of posts are printed out using an archive template. Each post's voting button has html data attributes containing the `vote-id` and the `vote-nonce`.

When the voting button is clicked an AJAX call is made containing the vote-id, and the vote-nonce. These should be verified server side but they appear to be failing `wp-verify-nonce`. Debugging and echoing the posted data confirms that it is identical to the original data.

AJAX PHP Function:

```
function submit_vote() {
    $vote_id = intval($_POST['vote_id']);
    $vote_nonce = sanitize_text_field($_POST['vote_nonce']);
    $action = sanitize_text_field($_POST['vote_nonce']);

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce($vote_nonce,'vote-nonce-' . $vote_id))
        die(-1);

    $response = json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) );
    die($response);
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_submit_vote', 'submit_vote' );
```

NONCE Generation:

```
wp_create_nonce( 'vote-nonce-' . get_the_ID() );
```

AJAX JavaScript call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".post-voting").click(function(){
    vote_nonce = jQuery(this).data('vote-nonce');
    vote_id = jQuery(this).data('vote-id');

    jQuery.post(
      vote_ajax.url,
      {
        action: 'submit_vote',
        vote_id: vote_id,
        vote_nonce: vote_nonce
      },
      function( data ) {
        alert( jQuery.parseJSON(data) );
      }
    );
  });
});
```

The ajax request appears to be just dying with an empty response (not -1)

Comment: The AJAX call will die with null data as per `die(-1)` which should be `die('-1')` for your voting system. Did you `var_dump( $_REQUEST )` to make sure all data are there?

Comment: yep, i've tried the var_dump and all the data is there.

Comment: Try this `wp_create_nonce( 'vote-nonce' )` and then `wp_verify_nonce($vote_nonce,'vote-nonce')`, to see if it has to do with the identifier

Comment: tried that as well. Didn't seem to make a difference. I'm wondering if it's something to do with my cookie paths, my admin bar isn't showing up in the front end. Do you know if the cookies are needed for nonce validation?

Comment: Yes. Nonces rely on `wp_get_session_token()` tokens which are based on cookies e.g `LOGGED_IN_COOKIE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify nonces in Ajax requests, [`check_ajax_referrer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_ajax_referer/) should be used instead of `wp_verify_nonce()`:

Crete the nonce:

```
$nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'vote-nonce-' . get_the_ID() );
```

Include it in JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".post-voting").click(function(){
    vote_nonce = <?php echo $nonce; ?>
    vote_id = jQuery(this).data('vote-id');

    jQuery.post(
      vote_ajax.url,
      {
        action: 'submit_vote',
        vote_id: vote_id,
        vote_nonce: vote_nonce
      },
      function( data ) {
        alert( jQuery.parseJSON(data) );
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Check in the ajax callback:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_submit_vote', 'submit_vote' );
function submit_vote() {

    $vote_id = intval( $_POST['vote_id'] );
    $vote_nonce_name = 'vote-nonce-' . $vote_id;

    // By default, check_ajax_referer dies if nonce can not been verified
    if( ! check_ajax_referer( $vote_nonce_name, 'vote_nonce', false ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    } else {
        wp_send_json_success();
    }

}
```

Comment: using the check_ajax_referer and the cookie issue I mentioned above seems to have resolved my issue